# Launch Ansible playbook containing vault file reference from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, ansible-2.x, ansible-vault

I have a Jenkinsfile trying to launch an Ansible playbook which references some parameters stored in an Ansible vault encrypted file.

Ansible is installed in version 2.4.0.0

Here is a snippet of my jenkins file:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: 'vault_token', variable: 'VAULT_TOKEN']]) {

                    ansiblePlaybook(
                            playbook: "./ansible/playbooks/deploy.yml",
                            inventory: "./ansible/hosts/hosts",
                            credentialsId: "$VAULT_TOKEN"
                }
```

And there is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: managers
  become: true
  tasks:
  - include_vars: ../vaults/passwords.yml
  - name: Log into Docker repository
    docker_login:
      registry: my.registry.org
      username: "{{ reg_user }}"
      password: "{{ reg_password }}"
```

This playbooks includes the vault file containing the encrypted values.
When Jenkins execute the Jenkinsfile, I get the following error:  ***Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found***

Why is ansible not using the credentialId i've passed to him in the Jenkinsfile and what is the good way to pass this credential?

Answer (score 3):

1. Please use 'vaultCredentialsId' instead of 'credentialsId' for vault token.
2. Remove 'withCredentials'part and straightaway write like vaultCredentialsId:'vault_token'
   [Ansible Plugin link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin#AnsiblePlugin-VaultCredentials)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'vault_token', variable: 'VAULT_TOKEN')]) {
        ansiblePlaybook colorized: true, credentialsId: '', forks: 10, inventory: 'ansible/hosts/hosts', limit: '', playbook: 'ansible/playbooks/deploy.yml', sudoUser: null, extras: "--vault-password-file ${VAULT_TOKEN}"
        }
```

you need to add the

> extras: "--vault-password-file ${VAULT_TOKEN}"

and leave credentialsId blank.